# Show selected point in ol3 with maxscale layer

Tags: openlayers, zoom

I have to display a layer with 14000 object. I use maxscale to limit zoom level displaying features. I want to select item on init but in the top level no item are loaded (maxscale).
Do you have a solution to show selected object on top level?